# Laravel package auto-discovery not finding Provider

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php

I'm creating my first package for Laravel, and I'm having trouble installing it correctly via composer.  It's using the Laravel (v5.5+) auto-discovery via the package's `composer.json`, but when it runs the `artisan package:discover` command, it can't find my custom ServiceProvider.  This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "mpemburn/api-consumer",
    "description": "Configurable consumer for RESTful API's",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": ["api","restful","laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mark Pemburn",
            "email": "mark@pemburn.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mpemburn\\ApiConsumer\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        },
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Mpemburn\\ApiConsumer\\ApiConsumerProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

...and this is `ApiConsumerProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace Mpemburn\ApiConsumer;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Mpemburn\ApiConsumer\Handlers\ResponseHandler;
use Mpemburn\ApiConsumer\Interfaces\ResponseHandlerInterface;

class ApiConsumerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        // Bind ResponseHandlerInterface class(es)
        app()->bind(ResponseHandlerInterface::class, ResponseHandler::class);
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../config/api-consumer.php' => config_path('api-consumer.php'),
        ], 'config');
    }
}
```

I've scrutinized this six ways from Sunday, and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

You can find the package here: https://github.com/mpemburn/api-consumer

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Edited to add: composer version 2.0.6, Laravel version 8.16.0

Answer (score 3):

Had a look at the github link - problem is that your service provider class file is not in the src directory

Move the `ApiConsumerProvider.php` inside the `src` directory then it should work.

Your psr4 autoload key points to the `src` directory for the `Mpemburn\ApiConsumer` namespace.

Comment: Huzzah @Donkarnash—that was it!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to delete both the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file, and then run `composer install` again.

(My thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1775#issuecomment-655553133) by [mohanad69](https://github.com/mohanad69).)

Comment: I had to do the same.